DAX Measure to Filter Table for Specific Events on Consecutive Dates
I need to filter a table using a DAX measure based on the following conditions:
For each unique UserID, if that user had an Activity of Run on First Day, an Activity of Run on any number of consecutive dates, and followed by any non-Run Activity and a Hobby of Garden, then keep those rows.
For example, consider the following table:



Date
UserID
Activity
Hobby




01/05/2020
01A
Run
Stamps


01/06/2020
01A
Run
Stamps


01/07/2020
01A
Walk
Garden


01/05/2020
02B
Run
Stamps


01/06/2020
02B
Run
Stamps


01/07/2020
02B
Run
Garden


01/08/2020
02B
Run
Garden


01/05/2020
03C
Run
Stamps


01/06/2020
03C
Run
Stamps


01/07/2020
03C
Walk
Garden


01/08/2020
03C
Walk
Garden


01/05/2020
04A
Run
Stamps


01/06/2020
04B
Run
Stamps


01/05/2020
04A
Run
Garden


01/08/2020
04B
Run
Garden


01/08/2022
04B
Run
Garden



The first three rows would be kept since UserID 01A ran for two consecutive days then walked and gardened.
The second set of four would be excluded because 02B run four days in a row, but didn't end the streak with a non-running activity.
Of the next set of four rows, only the first three would be kept, since the fourth day's non-running activity was not preceded by two or more days of running, despite gardening on that day.
The final five rows would all be excluded, because users had non-consecutive activities and hobbies that do not meet the criteria.  I included them to show the nature of the data in the table, which may have non-consecutive events and multiple events on the same day by a single user.

how exactly do you need to use that DAX measure? Filtering for the rows? Or aggregating them some way? Is it only DAX measure which can be used, or can it be a flag in a new column in Power Query (M) or DAX?

@MátéJuhász I'll need to show the average daily count of users who are left after the filtering in given time periods, the Year-To-Date and rolling 12-months average daily counts, across various facilities and so on.  I'm considering pulling back into setting up a new flag column using SQL before the dataset gets into to PowerBI as an alternative, but that is not the preferred method, per our architecture plan.

Although it can be done with SQL / DAX / M, it'll be complex code, difficult to adapt to new requirements (e.g. what happens if a same users has multiple intervals) and inefficient (could be very slow for big datasets). I think a small python / R code performing this calculation would be much better.

you can try to create a column.
Column =
VAR _min =
    CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'Table'[Date] ), ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[UserID] ) )
VAR _max =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Table'[Date] ), ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[UserID] ) )
VAR _check =
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[Date] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[UserID] )
    )
        = DATEDIFF ( _min, _max, DAY ) + 1
VAR _walk =
    MINX (
        FILTER (
            'Table',
            'Table'[UserID] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[UserID] )
                && 'Table'[Activity] = "Walk"
        ),
        'Table'[Date]
    )
RETURN
    IF ( _check && NOT ( ISBLANK ( _walk ) ) && 'Table'[Date] <= _walk, 1, 0 )


